# (PYTHON, PILLOW) How to make RGBA image conversion to RGB faster?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, rgb, rgba

I'm making fade effect by merging .png image with .jpg, but the conversion process takes too long. Is there a way how I could speed up this process?

```
for f in range(101):
    print(str((200 + f) /3) + "%")
    if f == 0:
        im_rgba = img1.copy()
        im_rgba.putalpha(255)
        im_rgba = im_rgba.convert('RGB')
        im_rgba.save(crnt_dir + '/frames/img201.jpg', quality=5)
    elif f > 0:
        mask_im = img1.copy()
        mask_im.putalpha(int(255 - 255 / 100 * f))
        mask_im.save('mask_rect3.png', quality=5)
        if f <= 9:
            im_rgba = img1.copy()
            im_rgba.paste(img2, (0,0), mask_im)
            im_rgba = im_rgba.convert('RGB')
            im_rgba.save(crnt_dir + '/frames/img20'+str(f)+'.jpg', quality=5)
        elif f > 9 and f <= 99:
            im_rgba = img1.copy()
            im_rgba.paste(img2, (0,0), mask_im)
            im_rgba = im_rgba.convert('RGB')
            im_rgba.save(crnt_dir + '/frames/img2'+str(f)+'.jpg', quality=5)
        elif f > 99 and f <= 999:
            im_rgba = img1.copy()
            im_rgba.paste(img2, (0,0), mask_im)
            im_rgba = im_rgba.convert('RGB')
            im_rgba.save(crnt_dir + '/frames/img'+str(200 + f)+'.jpg', quality=5)
```

Comment: I believe you can use the same image object for both parameters of `paste`: `im_rgba.paste(img2, (0,0), img2)`.

Comment: If I understood you right, it will make img2 fully transparent, but I need to make it transparent gradually. These images will be took as frames for video, so I need smooth fade effect.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood, I thought the transparency was built into the PNG image.  Now I see what you're doing, you're giving a constant transparecy for the entire image.

Comment: How long does it currently take? What dimensions are your images? What are you planning to do with the output files - maybe you don't need to write them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that 99% of your time is spent reading and writing images.  The only way to be sure is to benchmark it, but that's my guess.  That means almost everything else you manage to improve will be negligible.

One thing you could do is eliminate the `save` of `mask_im`.  I don't know why you'd need it, and every iteration of the loop writes over the copy saved in the previous iteration.  It's easy to recreate if you need it again, so just eliminate the save and get back that wasted time.

Speaking of `mask_im`, you're creating it the hard way.  I don't expect this to make a measurable difference, but here's the easy way:

```
mask_im = PIL.Image.new('L', img1.size, int(255 - 255 / 100 * f))
```

One other observation unrelated to speed - your logic for breaking the output into different cases is over complicated and buggy.  For example you're writing two different files called `img201.jpg` and none called `img200.jpg`.  Since `f` is explicitly in the range of 0 to 100, there's no need to test that it's less than 999.  Just eliminate all the `if` statements and use the code from the last one in every case:

```
    im_rgba = img1.copy()
    im_rgba.paste(img2, (0,0), mask_im)
    im_rgba = im_rgba.convert('RGB')
    im_rgba.save(f'{crnt_dir}/frames/img{200 + f}.jpg', quality=5)
```

(I took the liberty of using an f-string to simplify the building of the file name)